# Is there a golang post-commit build process

Tags: git, go

Is anyone aware of an already done script that is useable for git post-commit building of GO source code so I can push to my test/prod servers on demand?

Answer (score 4):

This looks less than a post-build git trigger, and more as a continuous integration question, where you could link your go project (as described in [this blog post](http://jmcvetta.github.io/blog/2013/08/30/continuous-integration-for-go-code/)) to:

- [travis.org](https://travis-ci.org) (as [described here](http://jmcvetta.github.io/blog/2013/08/30/continuous-integration-for-go-code/#travis-ci))
- [drone.io](http://drone.io/) (as [mentioned here](http://jmcvetta.github.io/blog/2013/08/30/continuous-integration-for-go-code/#droneio))
  But also [**wecker**](http://wercker.com/), which does support deployment as well.

Locally, you could check [goconvey](http://goconvey.co/) which allows you to see if your code compile *and* your tests pass.

Then, if those tests are green, you can push yo your server (so "on demand"), but you don't need a hook for that.

Comment: To expand on the Travis CI approach: hook it into your repos (easy if they're on GitHub!) and call a CLI client (e.g. https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb to check the status of a job). For any of these services you can also write your own little script (Python, or even a Go program) to check `status: passed` (or similar).

Comment: Thumbs up for Travis CI